# Updating mongodb using multiple threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb

I have a huge database in which i have to find certain keywords in the "keywords" column. If i find the word i am searching for in the "keywords" column, then i update(increase by 1) another column "Counter" in the same tuple. 
What i want to do is, search for multiple keywords at the same time using threads, which increase the counter value as soon as it finds the keyword.

For eg: I want to search for "authentication" and "failure".
I run 2 threads for that
At the end the tuple with "Keywords" column as "Authentication, Failure" should have "Counter" value as 2
And the tuple with "Keywords" column value "Authentication, Passes" should have "Counter" value as 1.
And the tuple with "Keywords" column value "Security, Passes" should have "Counter" value as 0.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `$inc` on your threads you should get what you want.

EDIT:

Thread 1:

```
coll.update( { keywords: "authentification" }, { $inc: { counter: 1 } } );
```

Thread 2:

```
coll.update( { keywords: "failure" }, { $inc: { counter: 1 } } );
```

What you have to assure is, that the `keywords` property is either set with a `string` or an `array`.  If your source data looks like `"Authentication, Passes"` you have to parse it and make an `array` like `[ "authentification", "passes" ]` out of it.

Comment: All the threads are working on the DB at the same time.
And all the threads read the tuple values before anyone updates the "Counter" value.
For eg: If one tuple consists of both "Authentication" and "failure". The 2 threads working on DB read the value of "Counter" column as 0. And both of them updates it to 1, rathar than 0 to1 and 1 to 2

Comment: You do not have to read the tuple before updating. you can give the condition for updating in the first paramater of `update`. See my edit.